# UIKit Lightbox next button not working properly

Tags: slider, uikit, lightbox

I'm setting a slider with lightbox images inside, so you can see a bigger picture. The problem comes when the image is fullscreen. You need to press the next button 3 times in order to get to the next image. I don't know where I went wrong, as the console throws no error.

I've put the whole template in a codepen:

```
<div data-uk-slider class="uk-slidenav-position">
    <div class="uk-slider-container uk-container-center">
        <ul class="uk-slider uk-grid" data-uk-grid-match>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></a></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
            <li><a class="uk-display-block" href="" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'gallery'}"><img src=""/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <a href="" class="uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-previous" data-uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
    <a href="" class="uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-next" data-uk-slider-item="next"></a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/lord_enzo/pen/BZWzvb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently I'm blind and could not see that I hadn't closed any of the  tags. Putting in place all the  made it work!